# celery log shows "Permission Denied"

Tags: python, windows, flask, celery

I'm running celery on Windows, and there's a task that writes a file on a network drive. Looks like it's having issue to write due to permission. Here's part of celery log that shows the error:

```
 File "C:\TaskerApp\FlaskApps\Tasker\tasks.py", line 194, in export
 with open(filename, 'wb') as w:
 IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'//saab/Data/5863/5-Message/5863_2M.txt'
```

And this is the original code:

```
@celery.task(name="tasks.export")
def export(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as w:
        w.write('test')
```

However when I try to write the file directly from python command line, I don't see any issue.

Just wonder what is the possible reason to cause this issue?
[image]

Comment: How do you run Celery? Is it running as a different user than you are using in the command line?

Comment: @dirn I set it up as a windows service. And under the service it uses Local System account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this work. Looks like the service is running under Local System Account, after I share the file path with this local account, the issue went away.